# Issues arranging groupbox in gridlayout in nxn format

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the issue with a project am working on. It's actually a school management system. What i basically want to do is create a frame that displays a group box in maybe 3 columns and n rows, depending on the length of data from the database. I manage to create it but am having problem making the frame resize itself to display the groupbox properly and also spacing out the groupbox. I will appreciate a simple sample.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What code do you have a problem with and have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need. When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I've been able to get my way around it.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
         
        self.create_gui()
        self.create_boxes()
    
    def create_gui(self):
    
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 920, 560)
    
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    
        self.staff_scroll = QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.staff_scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.centralwidget_layout.addWidget(self.staff_scroll, 0, 0)
    
        self.staff_scroll_content = QWidget()
        self.staff_scroll_content.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1000, 200))   
        self.staff_scroll_layout = QGridLayout(self.staff_scroll_content)
    
        self.staff_main = QFrame(self.staff_scroll_content)
        self.staff_main_layout = QGridLayout(self.staff_main)

        self.staff_grid = QGridLayout()
        self.staff_main_layout.addLayout(self.staff_grid, 0, 0)
    
        self.staff_scroll_layout.addWidget(self.staff_main, 0, 0)
    
        self.staff_scroll.setWidget(self.staff_scroll_content)
    
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
    def create_boxes(self):
        number = 1000
        columns = 3
        for index in range(number):            
            x = index // columns
            y = index % columns
            self.staff_sub = QGroupBox()
            self.staff_sub.setFixedSize(250, 130)
            self.staff_grid.addWidget(self.staff_sub, x, y)

            self.staff_dp = QLabel(self.staff_sub)
            self.staff_dp.setGeometry(5, 65, 60, 60)
            self.staff_dp.setPixmap(self.pxmap)
            self.staff_dp.setScaledContents(True)
             
            self.staff_name = QLabel(self.staff_sub)
            self.staff_name.setGeometry(80, 60, 160, 25)
            self.staff_name.setText(str(self.result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just need some more help. I was able to get my way to automatically create the group boxes i.

My problem now is that I have some data i want to pass from sqlite database, a list of staff name and their picture to the group boxes. I will appreciate a demo. The code above was how I created the groupbox and I want each to carry those informations. Thanks in advance.